# How to upload a file in node.js with multiple cateogries

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and trying to build an ebook store with node.js but I am not able to figure out how can I upload a book, that it can appear in multiple cateogires. For eg:- If I upload a book that is in spanish and is of physics. So, it should appear in two cateogries Spanish and physics.

I am completely new and struggling with node, If I need to learn anything new which can make development of book store easy please suggest it.

Comment: Looks like it is not a question to node.js, but question to your database structure. Do you have database btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view. Upload your file first, Then add the created reference/path with your categories that will save some disk space.

-- Schema --

```
const bbookSchema = {
  name: String,
  category:[String],
  file: String
}
```

-- Upload file first -- Get its URL --

then

```
{ name: "some book name", category: ["spanish", "physics"], file: "some-img/from/location"}
```

Save this format. It will save you a lot.